# JavaFx Canvas only resizes in height but not in width

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I have started programming this app for ploting temperature data, when the screen gets resized, the canvas should resize as well. It initializes correctly but when I want to resize the window, the draw() method will only resize the height, according to the stackpanes height value it is bound to but it will ignore the width entirely. The Listener won't even fire. This I find very strange. Also I have to set the minSize for the StackPane, otherwise nothing will be draw at all. I'm not using FXML.

Does anybody have any ideas?

**Edit** I changed line 58 from setRight() to setCenter, as mentioned in the solution from InternetUnexplorer. But I was still curious about why it is so, so I did some research. I found this in the internet:

- Top/Bottom area: Can shrink/expand horizontally and keep the height
  unchanged.
- Left/Right area: Can shrink/expand vertically and keep the    length
  unchanged.
- Center area: Can shrink/expand in both directions.

http://o7planning.org/en/10629/javafx-borderpane-layout-tutorial

Here my main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
        TempViewerWindow view = new TempViewerWindow();
        ReadData controller = new ReadData(view);
        controller.selectAll();

        mainStage.setScene(new Scene(view));
        //mainStage.setMinWidth(500);
        //mainStage.setMinHeight(400);
        mainStage.setTitle("Temperature Viewer");
        mainStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }

}
```

And here my view class:

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class TempViewerWindow extends BorderPane {

    public TableView<TempData> tableView;
    public Canvas canvas;
    public GraphicsContext gc;
    public StackPane holder;

    public TempViewerWindow() {
        tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<TempData, String> col_date = new TableColumn<>("Date");
        TableColumn<TempData, Float> col_temperature = new TableColumn<>("Temperature");

        col_date.setCellValueFactory(e -> e.getValue()
                                           .dateProperty());
        col_temperature.setCellValueFactory(e -> e.getValue()
                                                  .temperatureProperty()
                                                  .asObject());

        tableView.getColumns()
                 .addAll(col_date, col_temperature);

        setLeft(tableView);

        holder = new StackPane();
        holder.setMinSize(400, 400); // must be here for some reason

        canvas = new Canvas();

        gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        canvas.widthProperty()
              .bind(holder.widthProperty()
                          .subtract(10));
        canvas.heightProperty()
              .bind(holder.heightProperty()
                          .subtract(10));

        canvas.widthProperty()
              .addListener(observable -> redraw(gc));
        canvas.heightProperty()
              .addListener(observable -> redraw(gc));

        holder.getChildren()
              .add(canvas);

        setCenter(holder); //here was the bug

    }

    private void redraw(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        System.out.println("redraw!");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your canvas is being placed in the right of your BorderPane, when you should be placing it in the center.

If you change line 54 of `TempViewerWindow` from `setRight(holder)` to `setCenter(holder)`, the scaling works properly.

Comment: @fabian's answer provides a bit more explanation. Also, have you considered using a Chart instead of a Canvas to plot data?

Comment: I just had a look at Charts and will give it a try. It seems to fit my needs better than a canvas. But probably I should still code it all myself to get a better understanding of JavaFx?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `BorderPane` as parent for `holder`. The `holder` is used as right child of the `BorderPane`. However the right/left children are resized to their preferred widths and are resized to fill the height between the top and bottom nodes. (See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html))

> The `left` and `right` children will be resized to their preferred widths and extend the length between the `top` and `bottom` nodes.

If you'd use `holder` as `center`, it's width would be adjusted the way you expect it.

Alternatively you could use a `HBox` as base class for `TempViewerWindow` to achieve this kind of behavior.

```
public TempViewerWindow() {
    ...
    this.getChildren().addAll(tableView, holder);
    HBox.setHgrow(holder, Priority.ALWAYS);
    HBox.setHgrow(tableView, Priority.NEVER);
    this.setFillHeight(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explenation! I will give your alternative a try.